# Opengl rendering on iOS is out of focus after setting up manually, instead of using GLKit

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I was originally using GLKit to create an opengl context, but I needed to abandon it in order to create an opengl context on a separate thread. I have it running in a separate thread, but the picture is distorted, it looks blurry like putting the wrong prescription glasses. I followed this setup tutorial, but did it in Swift. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0. My app is in landscape by default. Everything is drawing, it just has this complete lack of focus to it. It was sharp and perfect when I created opengl through GLKViewController and used a GLKView, but I can't use these. Any idea's would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import OpenGLES

@objc class OpenGlView : UIView{
    var eaglLayer:CAEAGLLayer!;
    var context:EAGLContext!;
    var colorRenderBuffer:GLuint = 0;
    var depthBuffer:GLuint = 0;
    var glThread:NSThread!;
    var engine:Engine!;

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        setupLayer();
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        setupLayer();
    }


    func setEngine(engine:Engine){
        self.engine = engine;
    }

    func setupGL(){
        glThread = NSThread(target: self, selector: "glRun", object: nil);
        glThread.start();
    }

    func glRun(){
        //Start and run Opengl on a separate Thread
        setupContext();
        setupRenderBuffer();
        setupFrameBuffer();
        engine.setupEngine();
        setupDisplayLink();
        print("THREAD STARTED!");
    }

    private func setupLayer(){
        eaglLayer = self.layer as! CAEAGLLayer;
        eaglLayer.opaque = true;
    }

    private func setupContext(){
        let api:EAGLRenderingAPI = EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2;
        context = EAGLContext(API: api);
        if ((context == nil)) {
            print("Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (!EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(context)) {
            print("Failed to set current OpenGL context");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    private func setupRenderBuffer(){
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), colorRenderBuffer);
        context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), fromDrawable: eaglLayer);
    }

    private func setupFrameBuffer(){
        var framebuffer:GLuint = 0;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebuffer);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER),colorRenderBuffer);
    }



    private func setupDisplayLink(){
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "render");
        displayLink.frameInterval = 1;
        displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run();
    }

    func render(){
        engine.update();
        engine.draw();
        context.presentRenderbuffer(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER));

    }

    override static func layerClass() -> AnyClass{
        return CAEAGLLayer.self;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that the issue was retina screens. GLKView automatically handle's this, but if you are setting up opengl in your own view you need to handle it with this,

```
self.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
```

You also need to scale your  glViewport() to the scaled value.

**Edit:**

**Use UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale, see comment below.**

Comment: Actually what you want is [`nativeScale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeScale), not just `scale` -- if you're on an iPhone 6/6s Plus, `scale` is 3x, which means you're rendering more pixels than you're displaying and losing performance. Native scale lets you use a renderbuffer that goes straight to the display hardware without any further scaling.

Comment: Wow thanks rickster! You saved me a lot of potential trouble.